# Grails XML marshalling: change default "<list>" root element name

Tags: java, xml, grails, serialization, marshalling

By default Grails renders List in XML with a `<list>` element tag at its root. Likewise it renders Map with `<map>`. I would like to control the name of the root element.

If I'm returning an ArrayList of User, then I'd like to see:

```
<users>
    <user>...</user>
    <user>...</user>
</users>
```

**How can I achieve the above? Here are the Requirements:**

- Easy to apply this serialization for 50+ domain classes
- Abstracted from developers so no explicit coding is required during rendering domain objects (i.e., when `render()` or `respond()` is invoked, an ArrayList is still passed in, no explicit casting/converting like `as MyNewType`)
- Able to handle the edge case of an empty list (should return `<users/>`)

Nice-to-haves:

- If this formula can be applied to Map as well, great :)

I have been semi-successful in achieving the goals above, except I don't know how to account for the empty list case. I implemented my own ObjectMarshaller which renders all objects of type `List`. So long as the list contains one element, I can check the element's type and determine what the plural tag name should be (User => users). But if the list is empty, and since Java generics are by erasure (unless that's different in Groovy?) then I have no way to properly name an empty list other than defaulting to something like `<list/>`, which is not acceptable.

Some resources that I've been through:

- http://www.cacoethes.co.uk/blog/groovyandgrails/dry-json-and-xml-with-grails
- http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Custom-XML-Marshaller-change-the-root-element-name-td4649949.html
- http://jwicz.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/grails-custom-xml-marshaller/
- http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2013/11/grails-goodness-register-custom.html
- http://manbuildswebsite.com/2010/02/15/rendering-json-in-grails-part-3-customise-your-json-with-object-marshallers/

Answer (score 3):

A way to achieve this is to write a subclass for the CollectionMarshaller class and register it in our Grails application. We can for example register a custom implementation in BootStrap.groovy with the following code:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.xml.CollectionMarshaller
import grails.converters.XML

class BootStrap {

  def init = { servletContext ->
    // Register custom collection marshaller for List with User instances.
    // The root element name is set to users.
    XML.registerObjectMarshaller(new CollectionMarshaller() {
        @Override
        public boolean supports(Object object) {
            object instanceof List<User>
        }

        @Override
        String getElementName(final Object o) {
            'users'
        }
    })
  }
}
```

To make this work for more domain classes we might get a reference to all domain classes in BootStrap.groovy and loop through them to configure custom CollectionMarshaller instances.

For maps you can extend MapMarshaller

Also described in http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2014/02/grails-goodness-customize-root-element.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your example is basically what I had done yesterday (the "semi-successful" solution I mentioned). The problem with this solution is that Groovy generics are by erasure, just like Java, so your `object instanceof List<User>` will return `true` for any type of list, even a `List<String>`. I'll update my question to  bullet a list of "requirements" so it's clear what I will need. Thanks again though.