# How to customize the root element name for an object XML marshaller in Grails

Tags: xml, grails

I'm using Grails 2.5.3 and have a domain class Person.

I created an XML marshaller of Person, and it creats an XML with "person" as the root element name. Depending on the role of the person I would like to name the root element "patient" or "doctor", but there is no documentation in Grails, nor on implementers web sites about this.

The only thing I could find is how to customize the root element name for collection XML marshallers, like: [Grails XML marshalling: change default "<list>" root element name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592731/grails-xml-marshalling-change-default-list-root-element-name)

**Is there any way of customizing the root element name for object XML marshallers?**

What I have currently is:

```
XML.registerObjectMarshaller(Person) { person, xml ->
        xml.build {
          uid(person.uid)
          firstName(person.firstName)
          lastName(person.lastName)
          dob(person.dob)
          sex(person.sex)
          idCode(person.idCode)
          idType(person.idType)
          organizationUid(person.organizationUid)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `registerObjectMarshaller` method that you are using has an overload that takes an `ObjectMarshaller` instance. To override the name of the root element the marshaller you register needs to also implement the `NameAwareMarshaller` interface.

The answer in the post you linked handles all of this by registering an object that extends from `CollectionMarshaller` which is an implementer of both `ObjectMarshaller` and `NameAwareMarshaller`.

To customize the root element name the way you would like, you would need to create a class that implements `ObjectMarshaller` and `NameAwareMarshaller`.  Your usage of `registerObjectMarshaller` method is passing a closure which is being used by `ObjectMarshaller.marshallObject(...)`.  You can use the body of the closure in your new class's implementation of the marshalObject method.

```
class PersonMarshaller implements ObjectMarshaller<XML>, NameAwareMarshaller {

    boolean supports(Object object) {
        return object instanceof Person;
    }

    String getElementName(Object o) {
        if (object instanceof Patient) {
            return "patient";
        } else if (object instanceof Doctor) {
            return "doctor";
        } else {
            return "patient";
        }
    }

    void marshalObject(Object object, XML xml) {
        Person person = (Person) object;

        xml.build {
          uid(person.uid)
          firstName(person.firstName)
          lastName(person.lastName)
          dob(person.dob)
          sex(person.sex)
          idCode(person.idCode)
          idType(person.idType)
          organizationUid(person.organizationUid)
        }
    }
}
```